# Why isn't my CSS code to change the option tag background color when hovered or focused working in Chrome and mobile view?

Tags: html, css

**How to change the background color of option tag when hovered or focused?**

Hello, in chrome when hovered on  dropdown the  changes background color and text color. Now I believe these are chrome's default style as I explicitly haven't styled . I have provided image for reference below.

[Picture of the dropdown in desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGJyV.png)

Another problem arises when I open the site in mobile view, when focused, the changes in  caused it to have very low color contrast and contents are barely readable.

[Picture of the dropdown in mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LISOD.png)

here is the HTML in DOM

```
<select
  id="nf-field-6"
  name="nf-field-6"
  aria-invalid="false"
  aria-describedby="nf-error-6"
  class="ninja-forms-field nf-element"
  aria-labelledby="nf-label-field-6"
>
  <option value="AL" selected="selected">Alabama</option>

  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>

  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>

  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>

  <option value="CA">California</option>

  <option value="CO">Colorado</option>

</select>
```

I tried using this code to have a different background color on hover/focused.

```
select#nf-field-6 > option:hover,
select#nf-field-6 > option:focus
{
    background-color:#084d91 !important;
}
```

But no changes were observed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if plugins have more selector (class or id) and have an `!importtant`   then your will be overridden.

Comment: Have a search around for how to style the select element and options. It's very limited what you can do and if you really want to change things on hover you will probably end up having to create your own select-type system.